# df to csv, paste -d for multiline variables, shell not bash *nix

Tags: bash, shell

What I am trying to achieve is parse and present simple 'df -h' output in CSV delimited way. But using shell - not bash, script.

What worked for me in a bash was pretty simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get fields from DF seprately

source=$(df -h --output=source)
fstype=$(df -h --output=fstype)
size=$(df -h --output=size)
used=$(df -h --output=used)
avail=$(df -h --output=avail)
pcent=$(df -h --output=pcent)
target=$(df -h --output=target)

paste -d'|' <(echo "$source ") <(echo "$avail") <(echo "$size") <(echo "$used") <(echo "$avail") <(echo "$pcent") <(echo "$target")
```

Now I am trying to achieve a better portability and make it into a Shell script and not bash, and that's where I start hitting issues like:

```
[root@so1 ~]# ./2test.sh
./2test.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./2test.sh: line 12: `paste -d'|' <(echo "$source ") <(echo "$avail") <(echo "$size") <(echo "$used") <(echo "$avail") <(echo "$pcent") <(echo "$target")'
```

Which I understand come from me using the process substitution, which won't work in SH.

The workaround I did was:

```
#!/bin/sh

df -h --output=source > tmp1.txt
df -h --output=fstype > tmp2.txt

paste -d'|' tmp1.txt tmp2.txt
rm tmp1.txt tmp2.txt
```

But that just not a beautiful solution, it means files are created/removed and that is just not pretty.

Any recommendation would be welcome to actually get that working better.

Ah yeah, what I want to achieve is what 'paste' is best at here. Modular script that would allow me to change delimiter to anything. Example output would be:

```
Filesystem|Avail| Size| Used|Avail|Use%|Mounted on
devtmpfs| 459M| 459M|    0| 459M|  0%|/dev
tmpfs| 482M| 482M|    0| 482M|  0%|/dev/shm
tmpfs| 469M| 482M|  13M| 469M|  3%|/run
tmpfs| 482M| 482M|    0| 482M|  0%|/sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1|  45G|  50G| 5.7G|  45G| 12%|/
tmpfs|  97M|  97M|    0|  97M|  0%|/run/user/2023
//10.202.21.222/c$/tmp/Advanced Lab Test |  26G|  50G|  25G|  26G| 49%|/mnt
```

or

```
[root@so1 ~]# ./2test.sh
Filesystem,Avail, Size, Used,Avail,Use%,Mounted on
devtmpfs, 459M, 459M,    0, 459M,  0%,/dev
tmpfs, 482M, 482M,    0, 482M,  0%,/dev/shm
tmpfs, 469M, 482M,  13M, 469M,  3%,/run
tmpfs, 482M, 482M,    0, 482M,  0%,/sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1,  45G,  50G, 5.7G,  45G, 12%,/
tmpfs,  97M,  97M,    0,  97M,  0%,/run/user/2023
//10.202.21.222/c$/tmp/Advanced Lab Test ,  26G,  50G,  25G,  26G, 49%,/mnt
```

By just replacing delimiter in the script statement.

Comment: Please add output of `df -hP` to your question.

Comment: `"Now I am trying to achieve a better portability"`: I doubt if you can achieve that, since the `-h` and `--output` flags of `df` are not specified in POSIX. Even if the language constructs you've used in the script are portable.

Comment: Well that's not the way it will be looking at the end. What I am going to have is something along the lines of:
if [ "x$KERNEL" = "xLinux" ] ; then
    assertHaveCommand df  
    CMD='df --otput'

But I do not want to rely on the /bin/bash at the end. So what's going to happen is if it is linux it will do command X, MacOs will do Y, but at least the script itself will stay being SH not change the script depending on OS. Hope that explains it.

Comment: Calling `df` repeatedly is prone to race conditions. What if the mounts are not always listed in the same order? What if a volume is mounted or unmounted between runs?

Comment: I totally agree with that, that was just example that I could come up with to convey the point the best way. I have actually taken the "sed" answer below from Socowi. This seems to do what I want almost best so far. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the spaces in the first and last column you still can parse the whole table instead of using 7 individual `df`s. The trick is that only the first and last column may contain spaces and the last column can be fairly safely detected by `...% /...` (second last column ends with `%`, last column starts with `/` or `Mounted on`).

```
df -h --output=source,fstype,size,used,avail,pcent,target |
sed -E 's:^(.*[^ ]) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+) +([^ ]+%) (/.*|Mounted on)$:\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7:'
```

Only trailing spaces in the first column would be cut off because we cannot tell them apart from the spaces separating the columns.

Comment: OP has `/tmp/Advanced Lab Test` with spaces :/ I was thinking about `tr -s ' ' '|'` but that would squeeze the spaces too :/

Comment: Thank you, fixed it. Now spaces are allowed in the first column too.

Comment: Thank you so much @Socowi. That was actually the most helpful answer, with the understanding of a task at hand. Including comment from @KamilCuk. That worked like a charm. I've even made extra test with making less spaces in a first column and it still worked. 

And it makes it very easily parsable later with awk and/or column:
```| awk -F "|" '{print $1}```
,
```| column -t -s '|'```

That's just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

> But that just not a beautiful solution, it means files are created/removed and that is just not pretty.
>
> Any recommendation would be welcome to actually get that working better.

In POSIX shell use temporary files to transfer the state. POSIX shell is not beautiful, nor fast, it's portable. Create temporary files with `mktemp`. Creating temporary files is **the way** to work in  shell.

Comment: Except that there is no `mktemp` command in POSIX.

Comment: Totally true - still, the most popular minimal environment without bash is busybox (standalone or alpine), and it has `mktemp`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Bash script isn't very idiomatic or elegant, either. I would turn to Awk for this.

```
df -hP | awk 'BEGIN { OFS="|" } { $1=$1 }1'
```

We set the output field separator to `|`, but we then also unfortunately have to force Awk to parse the line into fields; the silly `$1=$1` does that.

Comment: this will not work for the fields with spaces in them.  Even the header has "Mounted on"

Comment: That's only in the header, so easy enough to work around.

Comment: But then "mounted on" and "filesystem" can contain spaces. And that's what I am fighting with. I am not trying to make it work with just 1 example of the same amount of spaces or just kill those spaces. I am trying ti make something universal that would always use the first and last columns as is with spaces.

Comment: Then you probably need to hard-code column widths, as there is no way to reliably guess which spaces are column separators. If you know that column separators are always more than one space and the data will not contain two adjacent spaces, that can be done, but this is still not generalizable to arbitrary inputs. More fundamentally, perhaps you can find machine-readable mount information, thoug `/proc` is not portable either (basically Linux only).